# jQueryUI tabs... appending content to inactive tab, content stays hidden when tab is clicked/activated

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

Hey all... I've got a jQueryUI tabs implementation that's pretty straightforward and working fine.  Well, was :)

I'm appending content to one of the tabs, while the tab is inactive.  When I click the tab, the content isn't visible.  Firebug shows it's there, but with a css attribute of display:none.

I imagine that when a tab is inactive, all of the content within is set to display:none;, and when the tab is clicked, that content is set to display:block (or inline, not sure which).  I'm assuming that because I appended the extra content after the page loaded, jQuery isn't "aware" of it.  So guessing I need to work the .live() method in there somewhere, but not sure where, as it would seem that I'd have to manipulate the jQuery tabs code itself?

Don't really have any relevant code to post, as it's all pretty straightforward... but if anybody thinks it will help, I will throw some snippets up here.

To summarize... if appending data using jQuery's .append() to a node that's currently an inactive jQueryUI tab... how can I get that data to display when the tab becomes active?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should work with `append()` and jquery UI. Are you sure that you're appending data to tab data container only? I suppose you're doing something like [`working demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/MU8BL/) only.

Comment: Indeed, it does work.  I had code that manipulated another node within the tab, based on the class name of that node, and didnt realize the node I appended also had the same class name :(  I just assumed it wasn't showing up because it was appended dynamically.  Thanks for verifying that it should, as that stopped me from continuing down the wrong path looking for the solution.

Answer (score 2):

You're correct that when a tab is hidden, it's set to display: none; and when it's not, it's set to display: block;.  I tested your technique (using jQuery's append()), and it works fine for me.  Here is my test code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.6/themes/hot-sneaks/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" /> 
</head>
<body>
    Enter some HTML and hit Enter: <input id="add-content" style="width: 300px;" /><br /><br />
    <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="tabs-1">
            <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-2">
            <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. Duis scelerisque molestie turpis. Sed fringilla, massa eget luctus malesuada, metus eros molestie lectus, ut tempus eros massa ut dolor. Aenean aliquet fringilla sem. Suspendisse sed ligula in ligula suscipit aliquam. Praesent in eros vestibulum mi adipiscing adipiscing. Morbi facilisis. Curabitur ornare consequat nunc. Aenean vel metus. Ut posuere viverra nulla. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque convallis. Maecenas feugiat, tellus pellentesque pretium posuere, felis lorem euismod felis, eu ornare leo nisi vel felis. Mauris consectetur tortor et purus.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-3">
            <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vulputate, pede vel vehicula accumsan, mi neque rutrum erat, eu congue orci lorem eget lorem. Vestibulum non ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce sodales. Quisque eu urna vel enim commodo pellentesque. Praesent eu risus hendrerit ligula tempus pretium. Curabitur lorem enim, pretium nec, feugiat nec, luctus a, lacus.</p>
            <p>Duis cursus. Maecenas ligula eros, blandit nec, pharetra at, semper at, magna. Nullam ac lacus. Nulla facilisi. Praesent viverra justo vitae neque. Praesent blandit adipiscing velit. Suspendisse potenti. Donec mattis, pede vel pharetra blandit, magna ligula faucibus eros, id euismod lacus dolor eget odio. Nam scelerisque. Donec non libero sed nulla mattis commodo. Ut sagittis. Donec nisi lectus, feugiat porttitor, tempor ac, tempor vitae, pede. Aenean vehicula velit eu tellus interdum rutrum. Maecenas commodo. Pellentesque nec elit. Fusce in lacus. Vivamus a libero vitae lectus hendrerit hendrerit.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.6/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        (function ($) {
            $("#tabs").tabs();

            $('#add-content').change(function (e) {
                var $this = $(this);
                $('#tabs-2').append($this.val());
                $this.val('');
            });

        } (jQuery));
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

If you enter some HTML into the input box, and then go to the second tab, you'll see that it's appended to the second tab.